# Unique Variable Constraint in Gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, jupyter-notebook, linear-programming, gurobi

I am using Gurobi in Jupyter notebook with 9 variables. I want to add constraints so that each variable has a unique value. How do I code this in Gurobi Linear programming solver?

```
m.addConstr(i1 - i2 + y*a >= 1)
```

Based on my online research, the above is what I am currently trying to enforce but it is not working.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because optimization modeling belongs in or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit more constructive, this is called an **all-different constraint**. This is part of many Constraint Programming (CP) solvers. Implementing this constraint in a Mixed-Integer Programming model is not totally trivial or cheap. For some formulations see for instance: https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/ijoc.13.2.96.10515.